# Class '\App\User' not found after updating laravel 7 to 8.47

Tags: laravel, caching

I have tried everything I found regarding this issue... I am still getting that error

> "Class '\App\User' not found" in
> Illuminate\Auth\EloquentUserProvider::createModel
> vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/EloquentUserProvider.php:183.

The web project was initially developed in Laravel 7.  So I uploaded both composer.json and composer.lock on the web server and upgraded to Laravel 8 with composer install.

I then sync the following folders from local to web :

```
app, public, resources, routes & vendor.
```

Finally I run the following commands :

```
php artisan cache:clear, 
php artisan config:clear & 
php artisan config:cache.
```

I get the error after login in on my web project.  On the local project it works 100%, with all the table controllers in `App/Model`s including `App/Models/User` and properly referenced in all the files using it.

I don't know what else I can do... and I need this project [www.fairtradetourism.org](http://www.fairtradetourism.org) running by the end of this day.  Please help...

Comment: did you move the User model to a different namespace? and what do you mean you "synced the folders"?

Comment: Yes all the table controllers are in the App/Models folder.  I use Transmit on Mac to sync the folders from local to web so all the files are the same.  On local there is no error.

Comment: you mean the Models are in the `App\Models` namespace in the `app/Models` folder? ... did you update the `config/auth.php` file so it knows that the User model is in a different namespace?

Comment: You saved me.  Indeed that file was the little culprit.  I will write it in bold to remember!  Thank you so much @lagbox! Is it better to also sync the folder config from local to web?

Comment: np ... ideally you would have the whole project in a git repo then on the server it can just pull in the changes then you can run `composer install`, `artisan migrate`, `artisan config:cache` and be ready to go ... basically would pull in everything except for `vendor`

Comment: I looked at that process a while ago but it looked a bit complicated for me.  Can you recommend a good resource explaining how to do that?